# Query a location database based on the user's current location

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, html, geolocation

I have a database of locations where the two fields are longitude and latitude. When a user reaches the index page, I'd like to retrieve their location and then get every point inside the database in a certain distance radius from the user.

So far I have thought I could try to measure the distance with every point in the database but that could take a while if I have a lot of entries.

I'm using Python to build my app but I use Javascript and the Google Maps API to retrieve the location.

Does anyone know what I should use to do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: use a database with built-in geo features, like mongoDB

Comment: @dandavis Do you have a link to the documentation of any of such database? I looked at MongoDB but I can't find anything that has to do with my current problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your distance would translate to some angle you could add and subtract to your longitude and latitude. You could then filter your database based on that range, i.e. find the elements where the longitude is +- angle, etc. I would expect that this should be reasonable fast.

Note that if you have [lat_min,lat_max] and [long_min, long_max] you are drawing a rectangle rather a circle which might or might not be ok with you. If you need more accuracy, you could then start to calculate the actual distance of this smaller subset which should still be faster than calculating the distance for each point in the database.

**EDIT**

@dandavis had me looking... MySQL as well as MongoDB seem to support geospatial queries which is quite cool! [Here's](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/) a blog about MySQL features which includes the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html) to the dev site. Mongodb's docs for geospatial queries can be found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-geospatial/).

Comment: The blog link is exactly what I'm looking for, although I'm really lost as to how to implement that in a django project. But I guess this is another question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for location based queries in relational databases, postgresql is more matured compared to mysql.

Mongodb's goespactial queries are really good, if you are comfortable with NoSQL.

References:

[Mongo's geospacial indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/)

[Mysql spatial data types docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html)

Comment: I have never used NoSQL so I opted for MySQL although I have limited experience with it. Thank you for your help!